# Ionic Multiple Modal : Major Bug: Modal Stack does not Update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created this bug that has been bothering me for quite some time.

Here -- > [Ionic PlayGround](http://play.ionic.io/app/57a39564d962)

I have 4 modals. `ReadMore`, `Comments`, `Replies` and `Images`.

To recreate this follow this step:

`Open readmore Modal`. Inside which there is button to `open comment modal`. Click On it. Comment Modal opens up. Inside which there is another button for `replies modal`. Click on it.

Now **`close all the modals`**. and return to main page `Open Images Modal` (3rd Button), Inside which there is a button to `open Comments Modal`. Click On It--> **It dosen't open** , it does, but it **opens behind the currently opened Modal**. <---bug

I have raised an issue on github, but does any one know how to solve this problem?

Using ionic 1.0.0v

Comment: Can you provide code pen?

Comment: I did provide one. Its the ionic Playground.  See the link. There isn't a difference between playground and code pen.